# entity = Entity(pygame.Surface((100, 100))) TypeError: Entity() takes no arguments

Tags: python

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

W = 800
H = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font_path = 'mario_font.ttf'
font_large = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 48)
font_small = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 24)

game_over = False
retry_text = font_small.render('Нажмите любую клавишу', True, (255, 255, 255))
retry_rect = retry_text.get_rect()

retry_rect.midtop = (W // 2, H // 2)


class Entity:
    def _init_(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x_speed = 0
        self.y_speed = 0
        self.speed = 5
        self.is_out = False
        self.is_dead = False
        self.jump_speed = -12
        self.gravity = 0.5
        self.is_grounded = False

    def handle_input(self):
        pass

    def kill(self, dead_image):
        self.image = dead_image
        self.is_dead = True
        self.x_speed = -self.x_speed
        self.y_speed = self.jump_speed

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        self.y_speed += self.gravity
        self.rect.y += self.y_speed

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)


entity = Entity(pygame.Surface((100, 100)))

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    clock.tick(FPS)

    screen.fill((92, 148, 252))
    entity.update()
    entity.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
quit()
```

Comment: Наверное все же вместо `if e.tupe == pygame.QUIT` должно быть `if e.type == pygame.QUIT`

Comment: я tuple в pygame.event не вижу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def _init_(self, image):
        ^^^^^^
```

> Entity() takes no arguments

Подчёркивания должно быть два. С одним подчёркиванием питон не воспринимает этот метод класса как конструктор и считает, что `__init__` у вас вообще не описан, поэтому и возникает ошибка, что конструктор класса не ждёт никаких аргументов. Исправьте:

```
    def __init__(self, image):
```